# Method to see how a variable effect others variable

Tags: structure, relationship, analysis, multivariate-time-series

i've been working for some projects that involving spareparts life-time.

I have tabular data with numeric value.

I want to know if there any way to knowing that how if i changing 1 variable, i want to know how this change going to effect all the other variable.

i've looking for some method like dynamic system, unfortunately, they don't come in packages in python, so we seems going to do from scratch.

Currently i looking for SEM (Structural Equation Modelling) for solving this, but i'm not sure if this applicable since mostly SEM working to see how latent variable affect others all, not how the variable affect each other in a system.

Is there any method i can use to find the correlation, more over the dynamics of the system using data i have that python friendly ?

Many Thanks !

a method that maybe solve my problem